# Swapping two reference-type variables in C#

Tags: c#

I have two struct instances that have a reference-type variable. I want to swap those two variables, but my first guess on how to do this looks like it doesn't work. My code looks something like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    Bar m_bar;
}

void Main()
{
    Foo a = new Foo();
    Foo b = new Foo();

    //swapping the values of m_bar of a and b
    Bar temp = a.m_bar;
    a.m_bar = b.m_bar;
    b.m_bar = temp;
}
```

From what I could gather, it looks like since the variables are reference types, assigning `b.m_bar` to `a.m_bar` also assigns it to `temp`, messing up the swap.

So is my code wrong? If yes, what's the right way to swap two reference-type variables? If not, I guess my code messes up somewhere else.

Thanks!

Comment: "assigning b.m_bar to a.m_bar also assigns it to temp" - no, it doesn't; `temp` is an isolated snapshot of the reference as it was *at the time you stored it* (there *is* a way to do what you describe, but it requires special syntax - in particular "ref locals" - my point being: the code as shown should work fine)

Comment: Do you have the code that makes you think it isn't working? Note: mutable structs are *almost always* a bad idea (unless you really *really* know what you are doing, and even then: I'd probably advice against it, except in some very specific scenarios such as "ref structs")

Comment: Please share a [mcve] where we can see the issue.

Comment: First of all you code will not compile due to access level of `m_bar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in the question works fine, as shown in the minimal repro below. The confusion here is *almost certainly* something to do with mutable value-types; structs with mutable fields are *notorious* for confusion. I strongly recommend treating `Foo` as immutable, explicitly making it a `readonly struct` if your compiler supports it - something like:

```cs
    readonly struct Foo
    {
        public Bar Bar { get; }
        public Foo(Bar bar) => Bar = bar;
        // not shown: override ToString, GetHashCode and Equals
    }
```

But: with something more like your original code:

```cs
static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo a = new Foo { m_bar = new Bar("abc") };
        Foo b = new Foo { m_bar = new Bar("def") };

        System.Console.WriteLine("Before");
        System.Console.WriteLine($"a.m_bar: {a.m_bar}"); // abc
        System.Console.WriteLine($"b.m_bar: {b.m_bar}"); // def

        //swapping the values of m_bar of a and b
        Bar temp = a.m_bar;
        a.m_bar = b.m_bar;
        b.m_bar = temp;

        System.Console.WriteLine("After");
        System.Console.WriteLine($"a.m_bar: {a.m_bar}"); // def
        System.Console.WriteLine($"b.m_bar: {b.m_bar}"); // abc
    }

    struct Foo
    {   // note: public fields are usually a bad idea in any type
        // note: mutable fields on value-types are usually a bad idea
        public Bar m_bar;
    }

    class Bar
    {
        public string Name { get; }
        public override string ToString() => Name;
        public Bar(string name) => Name = name;
    }
}
```